# Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class

Tags: php, preg-split

```
$date could be "23/09/2012" or "23-09-2012" or "23\09\2012" 
preg_split('/[\/\-\\]/', $date);
```

Not sure why PHP keep throw `missing terminating ] error`?

Comment: do you need to escape hyphens?

Comment: @Xin Old regex had an error in it. Please see updated answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
preg_split('/[\/\-\\]/', $date);
                   ^escaping the closing ']'
```

Do the following instead, to remove ambiguity

```
preg_split('/[\/\-\\\\]/', $date);
```

There is no need to escape `-`, but you could use `\-` as well.

---

Code:

```
$date = 'as\sad-s/p';
$slices =  preg_split('/[\/\-\\\\]/', $date);
print_r($slices);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => as [1] => sad [2] => s [3] => p )
```

Comment: @Xin Chen : There was a mistake in my regex, due to which it wasn't splitting at `\\`. Please see updated answer.